# Arquivar entradas do teclado em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data

estou construindo um código para reter qualquer comando feito pelo teclado, eles serão publicados em um tópico da estrutura ROS para controlar um robô móvel. Não sou muito familiarizado com Python, o máximo que consegui a respeito de armazenamento de dados foi o código abaixo... Por exemplo, vamos supor que o direcional para esquerda seja digitado, preciso armazenar que ele foi pressionado para, só então, informar ao robô que ele deve se mover de tal maneira.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
arq = open('/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/robosmoveis2018/dados.txt', 'w')
text = """
Lista 
---
1
2
3
"""
arq.write(text)
arq.close()
```

Comment: Sua pergunta provavelmente vai ser fechada, mas enquanto isso vou deixar esse [link](https://panda.ime.usp.br/pensepy/static/pensepy/10-Arquivos/files.html), vai desde os conceitos básicos até isso que quer fazer, boa sorte ;)  E recomendo que faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321067/armazenar-entradas-do-teclado-em-python#)

Comment: Mas qual é o conteúdo desse `dados.txt` ? Se for os comandos em forma de texto não vejo como a sua pergunta seja diferente de um "como ler conteúdo de um arquivo em python ?", que já tem por ai várias. E a sua questão é em construir o arquivo ou ler ? Continua bem confusa e não clara a pergunta. Seja o mais objetivo possivel no que já tem feito, no que precisa de fazer, e de como precisa de que fiquei feito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das coisas mais fáceis de usar em Python para ler o teclado diretamente é a biblioteca  "[pygame](https://pygame.org)".

Com ela é possível obter informação sobre as teclas pressionadas em tempo real (sem ter que esperar o usuário digitar "enter") e obter informações sobre as teclas-seta e outras, o que usando só a E/S do terminal é bem complicado de fazer.

Pygame seria legal porque além de dar controle sobre a leitura do teclado e uma interface simples para desenhar numa janela, deixa você no controle total do programa - então o mesmo programa que lê o teclado pode trocar dados com o disposito externo (o robô, no caso), e até desenhar algum retorno na janela, para o usuário do programa.

Mas você vai precisar aprender um minimo de Python para conseguir fazer as coisas - é um projeto de complexidade fácil pra média, e não vai dar pra resolver perguntando todos os passos, ou por tentativa e erro. Se você lê inglêsm eu sugiro seguir o tutorial oficial em python.org  -senão, veja a documentação em português/traduzida aqui: https://wiki.python.org.br/DocumentacaoPython